# Caught between child dialog input parms (rock) and entity dialog requiring related record (hard place)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

CRM 2013 On-Premise

Hello,

First off this process is working and can move to prod but I would prefer a cleaner solution than what I hacked out.

I have custom entity E and it has a subgrid that shows the related records of custom entity Y.

Now there may be times where the user wants to change, add, etc, the related Y records....but they are not looking at the Y entity they are looking at X and seeing Y through the subgrid.

So I gave them a button that launches a dialog that walks them through the changes and this works fine.

The rock and the hard place come in when launching this dialog.

**One way** is to have a "catalyst" dialog associated with entity X (X_Dialog). This dialog calls child dialog associated with Y (Y_Dialog) and passes X record values to Y_Dialog.

The trouble comes in that in order for my X_Dialog to "see" the Y_Dialog I have to have a lookup field to Y on the X form...and worse it has to have an associated record. This forces me to create a "dummy" Y record and associate it to every X record just so the Y_dialog can be called from X_Dialog.

---

**The other way** is to launch the Y_Dialog directly but Y_Dialog takes input parameters and I have yet to read anything saying this can be done...and of course it throws errors.

This is the way I'd prefer as X_Dialog is useless and serves only to cause the user to click next twice so I can "launch" Y_Dialog. Further I could eliminate the dummy Y record and lookup relationship.

---

**One thought I had** was I am passing the X record ID when launching the dialog. I could grab that ID and send it to code that looks up said record then outputs the needed X record values as local dialog variables.

One difficulty with this thought is I don't know how to get the ID value that is passed into the dialog. I have yet to read how that is done.

FWIW if it helps here is the code I am using to launch my dialogs:

```
function LaunchDialog(dialogID, typeName, SubGridName)
{
  var recordId = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

  var serverUri = window.parent.Mscrm.CrmUri.create('/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx');

  window.showModalDialog(serverUri + '?DialogId=%7b' + dialogID + '%7d&EntityName=' + typeName + '&ObjectId=' + recordId, null, 'width=615,height=480,resizable=1,status=1,scrollbars=1');

  //refresh grid only
  window.parent.RefreshFulfillmentSubGrids(SubGridName);
}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need X-related data to modify Y? What sort of data are you passing in from one dialog to another? Also, you can avoid the extra "next" click by making the first dialog simply launch the second right away. Put your empty page into an if branch that's always false (if 1 == 0)

Comment: That would work as one option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How complicated is your dialog?

If it's only a handful of fields, you could use something like [JCL](https://github.com/paul-way/JCL) and a custom web resource.  Then you can fetch the fields from the passed in GUID, create the record, and finally refresh the subgrid after the record is created.

Comment: Well I figured something like that must be possible but my trouble is how do I obtain the passed in guid in a dialog? Do I make an input var of the same name and Msoft magically matches them up?